# How can I structure subtitles and text in two columns

Tags: spacing, two-column

I'm writing a Techinician User Manual, and I need to know how can I structure text like this figure:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in several ways. One is to use a table, here `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}
  \verb|latex| (or \verb|pdflatex|) \verb|myfile| & A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. \\
  \verb|makeindex myfile| & A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. \\
  \verb|latex| (or \verb|pdflatex|) \verb|myfile| & A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. \\
\end{tabularx}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative in this case since you have long labels could be to use a `list` and to indent the description. Here I used an indent of 7em.

```
\lipsum[2]

\noindent
\begin{list}{}{%
    \labelsep=0em
    \labelwidth=7em
    \leftmargin=7em
    \parsep=0pt
    \itemsep=0.3em
    \topsep=0.3em
  }
\item[\texttt{latex} (or \texttt{pdflatex}) \texttt{myfile}: ] A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows.
\item[\texttt{makeindex myfile}: ] A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows.
\item[\texttt{latex} (or \texttt{pdflatex}) \texttt{myfile}: ] A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows. A lot of text that spans several rows.
\end{list}

\lipsum[3]
```

[image]